# How to Retrieve Cookie Value using Jquery JS Cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am using a jQuery cookie plugin called [JS Cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) and what happens is that I am unable to retrieve the data or the value in the cookie. I would like to store the value of the cookie that was inputted on the text box and retrieve it in the text field when the page is visited again.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cookie_email = Cookies.get('user_email');
    $('#email_address').val(cookie_email);

    $('#test_button').click(function() {
        Cookies.set('user_email', email_address, {
            expires: 365
        });
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mue1amcm/

Comment: Are you testing only on JSFiddle? Or locally too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code doesn't work as you don't assign the `email_address` variable anywhere. You should change that value to use `$('#email_address').val()`.

Also note that your jsFiddle isn't setup correctly; your URL to the external cookie script goes to a Github page. You need to use a CDN link instead. Try this:

```
var cookie_email = Cookies.get('user_email');
$('#email_address').val(cookie_email);

$('#test_button').click(function() {
    Cookies.set('user_email', $('#email_address').val(), {
        expires: 365
    });
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/mue1amcm/1/)

Comment: I'm trying to test here, but even when I pass the parameters hardcoded, when I try to make a get, there is nothing on cookies.

Comment: Are you testing on a server? You cannot set a cookie when testing on the local file system. As you can see from the fiddle, it should be working fine

Comment: just a question, when I do this var myemail = $('#email_address').val();    
Cookies.set('user_email', myemail , it doesnt seem to work, isnt that suppose to be equal

Comment: Assuming that the `myemail` variable is set at the right time to capture user input it should work. If you're still having issues I would suggest you open a new question as it has now progressed to a logic flow problem. Remember to include the full code sample in the question, as well as exactly what you want to happen.